# Which algorithm is more accurate for calculation of the angle between 3D vectors?

Tags: python, vector, trigonometry, angle

Over the years I've came across a few algorithms to calculate the angle between two 3D vectors. As the image shows I've discarded acos and asin ones for their corner case issues.

I'm now down to two of them.

- Version A) atan(sub/add) using addition and subtraction of the normalized version of input vectors.
- Version B) atan2(crossnorm, dot) using the length of the cross product and the dot product of the input vectors.

I've read about them in different places but in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782769/215146), this answer states that atan method is better on smaller angles. I tried on my end but did not notice any issue on smaller angles. And I would like more insight about why one could be better than another. Or maybe insight about how ought I test them or which reference should I compare their output to.

I actually have a bias towards atan2 solution, Version B, because:

- I get the normalized axis of rotation for free in the process, with cross/crosslen.
- I use the power/sqrt only once, to get the length of the cross.
- I don't get division by 0, for when b == -a, where the add variable, in Version A, becomes 0.

That said if, indeed Version A is indeed more accurate I'll consider it for the operations I'm doing, instead of B, but I would like to understand better the reasons for it, maybe visualize it on my end too, and this way be more confident about adopting Version A, instead of Version B.

Here are live code versions of all: [repl.it](https://replit.com/@probiner/Angle-Between-Vectors-PY#main.py)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you read the chapter 12 in this paper https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf, linked from the other question? It goes into far more & better detail than many of us can, since it's written by the master himself.

Comment: @D0SBoots No I didn't, I just focused on the chapter mentioned, Mangled Angles. Will check. Thanks

Comment: @D0SBoots Oh sorry, chapter 12 is indeed Mangled Angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare methods empirically, you need a ground truth to compare against that is the actual accurate value. You need to compute this with arbitrary precision math, although you can use one of the existing algorithms to do it. Here's an example:

```py
import mpmath

mpmath.mp.dps = 50

def angle_atan_true(x, y):
    xnorm = mpmath.sqrt(mpmath.fdot(x, x))
    ynorm = mpmath.sqrt(mpmath.fdot(y, y))
    xprod = [mpmath.fmul(n, ynorm) for n in x]
    yprod = [mpmath.fmul(n, xnorm) for n in y]
    plus = [mpmath.fadd(*n) for n in zip(xprod, yprod)]
    minus = [mpmath.fsub(*n) for n in zip(xprod, yprod)]
    norm1 = mpmath.sqrt(mpmath.fdot(plus, plus))
    norm2 = mpmath.sqrt(mpmath.fdot(minus, minus))
    return mpmath.fmul(2, mpmath.atan2(norm2, norm1))

a = [1, 0, 0]
b = [1, 0, 1e-8]

print("a", a, ", b", b)
print("atan_true:", angle_atan_true(a, b))
```

```
a [1, 0, 0] , b [1, 0, 1e-08]
atan_true: 0.0000000099999999999999998758922749679513924973721774310726
```

(That won't be the exact value either, but it should be accurate to at least 40 places, more than sufficient to validate the machine-precision versions.)

You will also want to look at a variety of inputs, not just a handful. Looping through lots and plotting the error can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I used this code to check the values in Python and another language. I must say I could not find the catastrophic issue and over several samples the atan2() method usually had 0 distance or "less or equal" value to the atan method.

Given that, and the bias explained about. I will stick to it, atan2()

Thanks again

Comment: Why would you get division by 0? Both methods use atan2. The fact that you're arbitrarily using regular atan for one of them is probably why you're getting worse results.